# Problems with vtk HardwareSelector.py example - Only works intermittently

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to use the HardwareSelector.py example, given at https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/Visualization/HardwareSelector/
The only part I have changed is to replace "UserInput" with "MiddleButtonPressEvent".

The problem is this only works intermittently.

My goal with this is to take an stl file and find only those elements visible from a certain viewpoint.
I am using python 3.7.3 64bit and vtk 8.2.0. packaged in Anaconda.

I cannot seem to find any information on this problem but have tried creating a new anaconda environment and get the same problem. I am not an experienced programmer so am unsure what to try to solve this.

The expected result is a list of visible cells in the interactor window. This is only sometimes printed.
The rest of the time, the interactor window closes and there is no output in the terminal.

Ideally this would be solved although if anyone has any suggestions for a better method for obtaining these cells I would appreciate this instead.

This is my first time posting a question here so I appologise if I have missed any crucial information and would be happy to provide further details if/when requested.

edit - the code is now attached as requested (this is basically the same as the example code as stated before).

```
from __future__ import print_function

import vtk
import vtk.util.numpy_support as VN

# Callback for when selection is changed

# This is global - fix later.
ren1 = vtk.vtkRenderer()


def selectionCallback(caller, eventId):
    hsel = vtk.vtkHardwareSelector()
    hsel.SetFieldAssociation(vtk.vtkDataObject.FIELD_ASSOCIATION_CELLS)
    hsel.SetRenderer(ren1)

    x, y = caller.GetRenderWindow().GetSize()

    # Create a small area around clicked point for selector area
    hsel.SetArea(0, 0, x, y)
    res = hsel.Select()

    numNodes = res.GetNumberOfNodes()
    if (numNodes < 1):
        print("No visible cells")
    else:
        sel_node = res.GetNode(0)
        print('Visible cell IDs: ', VN.vtk_to_numpy(sel_node.GetSelectionList()).tolist())


def main():
    colors = vtk.vtkNamedColors()

    sphere = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
    sphere.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
    sphere.SetRadius(5.0)

    sphereMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    sphereMapper.SetInputConnection(sphere.GetOutputPort())

    sphereActor = vtk.vtkActor()
    sphereActor.SetMapper(sphereMapper)
    sphereActor.GetProperty().SetColor(colors.GetColor3d('Bisque'))

    ren1.AddActor(sphereActor)
    ren1.SetBackground(0.1, 0.2, 0.4)
    ren1.GetActiveCamera().ParallelProjectionOn()
    ren1.SetBackground(colors.GetColor3d('Navy'))

    renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renWin.AddRenderer(ren1)    
    renWin.SetSize(300, 300)
    renWin.Render()

    iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)
    iren.AddObserver('LeftButtonPressEvent', selectionCallback)

    style = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera()
    iren.SetInteractorStyle(style)
    renWin.GetInteractor().SetInteractorStyle(style)

    ren1.ResetCamera()
    renWin.Render()

    iren.Initialize()
    iren.Start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you have any code you can share?  Outside of just a link

Comment: I have added the code as you requested. This is just the same code as the example in the link with the exception of changing 'UserInput' to 'LeftButtonPressEvent'. I did this as I couldn't find out how to activate the userevent.

Comment: After asking this question on another site, it seems that the cause might be with the gpu and opengl. The link to the other question is:

https://discourse.vtk.org/t/visible-cell-selection-hardwareselector-py-example-is-not-working-reliably/1262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HardwareSelector.py example use "u" key to call selectionCallback()
So it print "Visible cell IDs" and you code work fine. Without Anaconda.
In lorensen`s example Hardselector may lost window, if mouse cursor out of example's window. So we have "Visible cell IDs:  [6711651]". But all work fine, if window maximized.
P.S. may be problem solved in discussion from you link?
hsel.SetArea(0, 0, x-1, y-1) instead hsel.SetArea(0, 0, x, y)

Comment: Thank you for responding and for your explination of what is required to activate "UserInput". Yes, the discussion in the link (provided again below) has the solution as you have stated. I had not got around to sharing it here until your comment reminded me. I shall mark this as the answer.
  
https://discourse.vtk.org/t/visible-cell-selection-hardwareselector-py-example-is-not-working-reliably/1262
  
Note:
  
For anyone having issues with a black screen upon the interactor window opening, there is also information about this in the link.